# $rootScope.path('/') not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

i have a register() function shown below.

```
<form class="form-auth" ng-submit="register()">
```

I have defined it as follows

```
$scope.register = function(){
$http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data){
  $rootScope.authenticated = true;
  $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
  $rootScope.path('!/');
});
```

};

The problem is the last line:

```
$rootScope.path('!/');
```

it doesn't take me to the path i direct it to. i have tried several variations, ('/') and (#!/) but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $location service, not $rootScope.

```
$location.path('/');
```